# Matrix no results equivalent?

Tags: matrix, playa

I have a Matrix field (parent) in a channel set to have exactly 4 rows. The rows feature a Playa drop-down. These will serve as promotional tiles in the page templates to cross-promote other pages in the site

In the templates I must always display 4 tiles so need to write a fallback so if only 3 are selected then 1 extra random tile is shown, if only 2 are selected then 2 extra random tiles are shown, etc.

I've got this working fine using the Search parameter, eg:

```
{parent search:child="not IS_EMPTY"}
    DO THIS
{/parent}
```

However, the problem I'm experiencing is what to do if no options are selected (i.e. all Playa fields/rows are empty). Ideally would be able to do an `{if no_results}` conditional but can't access from within the `{parent}` loop and because using search cannot access via a `{if parent:total_rows==0}` conditional.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `search:col_name=` parameter in combination with `:total_rows`:

```
{if '{parent:total_rows search:child="not IS_EMPTY"}' == 0}
    ...
{/if}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Brandon - sadly is returning the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/np/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code on line 61

Comment: You should be putting that *outside* your Matrix tag pair (unlike normal `no_results` tags). There's no syntax errors that I can tell – it's working for me! Maybe the error is coming from another part of your template?

Comment: Hmmm, if I comment out template is fine (thought wouldn't surprise me). Code sample is outside the Matrix loop)

{if '{cross_promotion:total_rows search:destination="not IS_EMPTY"}' == 0}DO THIS{/if}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brandon for the relpy. I couldn't get this to work in Matrix without returning a PHP error but was able to achieve the desired effect by using the native ExpressionEngine query module, eg

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE col_id_7 != '' && entry_id = '{entry_id}'"}
  {if no_results}
    {embed='embeds/footer-tiles' total_rows='0'}
  {/if}
{/exp:query}
```

If trying something similar you might need to run in an embedded template so as not to cause a conflicted {no_results} result!

Hope this helps somebody else!

Cole