# Conditionals in matrix field

Tags: matrix, conditionals

I have a matrix field called {gallery} it has a column with 2 checkboxes - public and private

I would like to show only the items marked private but would also like an optional message if there are no private items. This code does not work:

```
{gallery} {if publicprivate =="private"} {if no_results}
       No rows available
   {/if}  
 <li><img src="{imageupload}"/></li> {/if}  
{/gallery}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer does not quite solve my initial problem but it does allow me to show if a private gallery contains any photos:

I added 2 columns - public and private each with a P&T checkbox. In 'private' I set this to

```
1 : private
```

I created each gallery separately using

```
{gallery search:public="public"}<li><img src="{imageupload}"></li>{/gallery}
```

Then,  in the private gallery I added the following text to my title:

```
Private Gallery: ({gallery:sum col="private"}) images.
```

By having the private checkbox equalling a number I am able to output the number of images that the private gallery is showing by counting the 'private' column checks. 
This lets users know whether there are any images in this hidden gallery before they send a request to view the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix supports a search param, so I'm pretty sure this should do it:

```
{gallery search:publicprivate="=private"}
    {if no_results}no private items available{/if}
    <li><img src="{imageupload}" /></li>
{/gallery}
```

EDIT - alternatively you could try something more like this:

```
{if gallery:total_rows search:publicprivate="=private" > 0}
no private items available
{/if}
 {gallery search:publicprivate="=private"}
    <li><img src="{imageupload}" /></li>
{/gallery}
```

Comment: `{gallery search:publicprivate="private"}...` will show only the private images if they are available but I cannot output any text between the two tags

Comment: Ah. I found a thread that deals with something similar - using a query instead of the matrix fieldtype tag pair in order to get the no_results side of things:  http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6494/matrix-no-results-equivalent

Comment: +1 a million times - saved me a (`s/butt/boat/g`)load of trouble

Answer (score 0):

You could try this too:

```
{gallery}
    {if public}Public content here{/if}
    {if private}Private content here{/if}
{/gallery}
```

Comment: I can output the content ok - it is the ability to output a message if the private content does not exist that is causing me the problem

Comment: Where is the private/public content? Is it a row in the matrix field? If it is what is the field name and what kind of content is it?

Comment: The matrix columns contain a title, imageupload (safecracker field) and publicprivate checkbox - public, private